# Java - url.openConnection() and httpsUrlConnection.connect() is running slow when first called

Tags: java, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I found an interesting phenomenon when writing Java programs.

I had created 3 https connections to 3 different URLs, and I found that when I call `url.openConnection()` and `httpsUrlConnection.connect()` for the **FIRST** time, they took nearly `300ms` and `1s` to execute respectively, while during the second and third call, they took nearly `0ms`.

Are there any reasons for these performance difference?

BTW, is there something I can do to improve the performance?

FYI, all of the three httpsURLConnection look like this (`try-catch` is not shown):

```
Url url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
Utils.logTime(logger);
HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Utils.logTime(logger);
httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpsURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
httpsURLConnection.setReadTimeout(5 * 1000);
httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty(Utils.ACCEPT, Utils.ACCEPT_ALL);
httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty(Utils.ACCEPT_ENCODING, Utils.GZIP);
httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty(Utils.USER_AGENT, Utils.MOZILLA);
Utils.addCookiesToConnection(httpsURLConnection, cookieMap);
Utils.logTime(logger);
httpsURLConnection.connect();
Utils.logTime(logger);
```

And as you may assume, Utils and cookieMap are a class and a HashMap created by myself, so they shall not be the focus of solution.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably keep-alive, so only the first connection actually has to connect. Move closer to google?

Comment: Does keep-alive also work even if those three httpsurlconnections are independent instances?

Comment: The [`URLConnection.connect()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect--) says in part (emphasis added): *Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by this URL, **if such a connection has not already been established.***

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the time difference could be: the first time, socket connection needs to be established (from the source ip to the target ip and port). Once established, the same TCP connection could be reused. It's normal in network programming.

To improve efficiency and more control over the connection pooling, I would suggest considering [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)

Comment: Actually, I did not get your point. Three httpsurlconnections are independent, as they share neither the URL nor the httpsurlconnections instance. I could be wrong, but I don't think the TCP connection could be reused. Any more idea? Besides, is Apache HttpClient more efficient than build-in httpsurlconnections?